# Get Jenkins build failure cause in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am Jenkins beginner.
I want to inject 'reason behind build failure' as an environment variable through groovy script.
How to get build failure cause in groovy script ?

Answer (score 0):

// Get `build` variable value as per your jenkins jobs , I am taking one job out of all jobs in my organistaion in this example , You can follow your own jenkins methods to get the build number details to variable `build`  we are using and add `BUILD_STRING` in  function `reason` as per your generic errors .

```
def jobName = Hudson.instance.getJob('<ORG_NAME>').getItems()[0]

println jobName

def joblist = jobName.getItems()


println joblist[0]

def build = joblist[0].getLastBuild()

println build

println "Reason is : " 
reason(build)


def reason(build) {
    
                     
                          def BUILD_STRING1 = "Caused:"
                          def BUILD_STRING2 = "ERROR: "

                                build.getLog().eachLine { line ->
                                        if (line =~ /$BUILD_STRING1/ || line =~ /$BUILD_STRING2/ ) {
                                            println "error: $line"  }
                                                          }

                         }
```